# In an inner product space, if the matrix is symmetric, is an eigenspace necessarily orthogonal to the range space?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, orthogonality

Say I have 3 distinct eigenvalues for a symmetric matrix.

By the Spectral Theorem, the three eigenspaces are mutually orthogonal.

But, if I just wanted to compute the first eigenspace, corresponding to $\lambda_1$, would this eigenspace, which is the null space of the matrix A-$\lambda_1$, be orthogonal to the range space of A-$\lambda_1$?

I feel that all we can really say is that the nullity and rank of A-$\lambda_1$ add up to give the dimension of the whole space, and that there isn't an orthogonality connection here, except for when we compare eigenspaces with eigenspaces.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The null space of $A$ is always orthogonal to the range of $A^T$, for any matrix $A$. Now, exploit that $A$ is symmetric.

**Solution:**

Let $x$ be in the null space of $A$ and $y=A^T u$ be in the range of $A^T$. Then, we have
$$ x^T y = x^T A^T u = (Ax)^T u = 0^T u = 0. $$
Since $x$ and $y$ were arbitrary, it follows that the null space of $A$ and the range of $A^T$ are orthogonal.

If $A$ is symmetric, then the dimension formula shows that the null space of $A$ is in fact the orthogonal complement of the range of $A$.

Comment: Hi @user251257 - why is the null space of A orthogonal to the range of $A^T$?  Thanks,

Comment: @LebronJames expanded the answer.

Comment: Ahh...nice, simple proof, going back to the very basics of taking inner products to prove orthogonality - awesome answer.   Thanks so much, @user251257 :-)  Have a great night.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvalues are necessarily independent so, in an inner-product space, orthogonal.

If an n by n matrix is symmetric then there are $n$ **independent** eigenvectors.  Therefore, there exist eigenvectors, each of which spans a one dimensional vector space so the eigenvectors form an orthogonal basis for the entire space.

Comment: Please start using LaTeX, see this guide: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference Almost all of your posts need heavy editing